# Why is yum not installing my softwares on RHEL 6 ?

Tags: rhel, yum

I am trying to install `avr-gcc` using yum on a RHEL 6.

But I get this error.

```
[root@xilinx etc]# yum install avr-gcc
Loaded plugins: refresh-packagekit, rhnplugin
There was an error parsing the RHN proxy settings.
RHN support will be disabled.
Setting up Install Process
No package avr-gcc available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

I am getting this error for even `yum update`

What is the altertnative then ?

Comment: what does "grep -i prox /etc/yum.conf /etc/yum.repos.d/*" output?

Answer (score 1):

So does that package even exist? Try typing

```
yum search avr-gcc
```

You also should take a look in your /etc/yum.repos.d directory and look at your .repo setup.

In its simplest form it should look like this:

```
[base]
name=base repo
baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/os/$basesearch
gpgcheck=0
```

Comment: In this directory I have many .repo files, which one should I modify ?

Comment: Post the listing of that directory...

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
yum -y install avr-gcc*
```

If it does not work, search for the package in the repository:

```
yum search avr
yum search avr-gcc
```

Comment: Read the OP's Q. He' having issues with yum on RHEL. This adds nothing new to this thread and should be deleted.